# Switch improvement using a generic case

Tags: c, performance, for-loop, switch-statement

Is it possible to change this 'switch'? First I though I could use a 'for' instead but I think it is not necessary anymore. The objective is to make this code more efficient. Do anyone know how to do this improvement to make the code more efficient? I am still learning about programming and I am not so experienced. I already did something but I do not know if it lacks something I put the new code under the old one. I think it may be necessary to use a if instead of the for I created or other function because I can not change the value of 'PageNumber' I just have to use it. Perhaps I do not need to use anything just what is already inside the 'case's. Someone can clarify me this?

```
switch (PageNumber) {

            case 0x01:
                m = 0;
                for (n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
                    if (n < NumberOfSensor) {
                        if (n < 4) {
                            Write_string("L       ", n, 0);
                            Write_int((n + 1), n, 1);
                            write_CustonCharacter(4, n, 3); //Write the indicator "->"


Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], n, 5);
                            } else if (n > 3) {
                                Write_string("L       ", (n - 4), 10);
                                Write_int((n + 1), (n - 4), 11);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, (n - 4), 13); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], (n - 4), 15);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    break;


                    /*
                     * PAGE 2
                     */
                case 0x02:

                    m = 0;
                    for (n = 8; n < 16; n++) {
                        if (n < NumberOfSensor) {
                            if (n < 12) {
                                Write_string("L       ", (n - 8), 0);
                                Write_int((n + 1), (n - 8), 1);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, (n - 8), 3); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], (n - 8), 5);
                            } else if (n > 11) {
                                Write_string("L       ", (n - 12), 10);
                                Write_int((n + 1), (n - 12), 11);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, (n - 12), 13); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], (n - 12), 15);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    break;


                    //...(This part is just repetition)

                    /*
                     * PAGE 8
                     */
                case 0x08:
                    m = 0;
                    for (n = 56; n < 65; n++) {
                        if (n < NumberOfSensor) {
                            if (n < 60) {
                                Write_string("L       ", (n - 56), 0);
                                Write_int((n + 1), (n - 56), 1);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, (n - 56), 3); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], (n - 56), 5);
                            } else if (n > 59) {
                                Write_string("L       ", (n - 60), 10);
                                Write_int((n + 1), (n - 60), 11);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, (n - 60), 13); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], (n - 60), 15);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
//==========================================================================
                for (PageNumber = 1; PageNumber < 9; PageNumber++) { //actually I think this for is not necessary because it receives PageNumber and then it does what it needs to do.
                    m = 0; //but does it need something else?
                    for (n = (PageNumber * 8 - 8); n < (PageNumber * 8); n++) {
                        if (n < NumberOfSensor) {
                            if (n < (PageNumber * 8 - 4)) {
                                Write_string("L       ", n - (PageNumber * 8 - 8), 0);
                                Write_int((n + 1), n - (PageNumber * 8 - 8), 1);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, n - (PageNumber * 8 - 8), 3); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], n - (PageNumber * 8 - 8), 5);
                            } else if (n > (PageNumber * 8 - 5)) {
                                Write_string("L       ", n - (PageNumber * 8 - 4), 10);
                                Write_int((n + 1), n - (PageNumber * 8 - 4), 11);
                                write_CustonCharacter(4, n - (PageNumber * 8 - 4), 13); //Write the indicator "->"
                                Write_int(Sensor_Count[n], n - (PageNumber * 8 - 4), 15);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
```

Comment: Half of your question is code that has been commented... please provide only a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: your code is badly indented, bad spelling convention (`write_CustonCharacter` vs `Write_int`) and I don't know what those `Write*` functions are used for. You should describe what the code is supposed to do. But if it works then this is more suitable on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would say that this code is not efficient mainly because it's repeating itself, and not because of memory usage.

How can you improve it in that aspect - you can have only one for-loop and no switch-case at all.

How? Try to express the for-loop in each of the cases as a function of the case's value, and then to generalize it according to the other for-loops bodies. For example:

Note that, for each case:

- The initial value of the for loop is always `(PageNumber-1)*8`
- The for-loop condition is always `n < PageNumber*8`
- The first line inside the `if-then` clause is always `Write_string("L       ", (n-((PageNumber-1)*8), 0));`

And so on.
Continue to generalize every number that changes as a function of `PageNumber` and then you'll end up having only one for-loop and no switch-case at all.

Comment: I tried to solve it. I put the new code under the old one. Could you please take a look?

Comment: The external for-loop shouldn't be there - according to question your code should just run once for a given `PageNumber`.

Comment: Another small code improvement - look how many times you're repeating `PageNumber * 8 - 8` (which is actually `(PageNumber-1) * 8`) and `PageNumber * 8 - 4`. Instead, save them in two variables and use the these variables. Your code will be smaller and cleaner.